# How to Increment the ID value in Cassandra Table Automatically?

Tags: cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I have a challenge when I am inserting a values in Cassandra table , I have one column name is "ID", this ID column values are increase the automatically like mysql auto_increment column. I think Counter DataType is not suitable in this Scenario.  Please any one help me to design the Schema, I don't want use the UUID's also for Replace the ID column

Answer (score 2):

In short I don't believe it is possible. The nature of Cassandra is that it does not do a read before write. With only one exception, lightweight transactions, but all they do is what's called "compare and swap", but there is no way, the autoincrement can be implemented on the server side.

Even with counters, you won't be able to achieve the desired result, if you increase the counter every time you add a record to the table, because you will not know whether the current value (even if it is totally consistent), is a result of an increment from your process, or from a concurrent process.

The only way is to implement this mechanism on the application side.

Comment: You are right -- Cassandra does not handle this kind of scenario! plus one

Comment: Thanks for your Reply .Do you have any Idea how to implement the above concept from Application Side using Java

Comment: I don't have any specific implementation of that in mind, since a lot of design details depend on a particular use case and app design. But this should be some kind of a synchronization layer that will be assigning sequential Ids to the requests, or allocating ranges of Ids to the applications per request, keeping its own counter, and implementing its own locking mechanism. This of course will slow down the write operations  because of the request concurrency.

Comment: Maybe if you explain your architecture goals - why do you need to have a sequential Id, the community can propose a different design accomplishing the same goals.

Comment: We dont need sequential Ids, those ids are should be the numbers but those should be unique numbers never be a duplicate values(like UUIDS).

Comment: By the architecture goals I meant a bigger picture than just creating unique integer Ids. A lot of times trying to bring design patterns from a relational world are not a right thing to do when designing schema for NoSQL databases like Cassandra. 
Most of the time, understanding the philosophy behind the distributed databases engine help to design the application to utilize its advantages without a need to bring the inappropriate patterns.

Comment: But if there is an absolute need to introduce something like what you want, then you have several options. Obviously you need a synchronization layer. This can be implemented using queuing layer, where the app is writing to, like Kafka for instance.

Comment: Then the consumer of these queues will have to assign these ids before writing data to Cassandra. How you accomplish full synchronization - it is a different story. You can have a central service which will allocate a range of Ids to each requester, to avoid calls for individual Ids. Then when the requester exhausts these Ids, it calls for the next range, and so on. I'll leave the implementation of this service alone.